# How I can make the iOS WebView element fullscreen?

Tags: webview, xamarin, element, fullscreen

How I can make the iOS WebView Element FullScreen?
(iPhone Retina (4-inch)

Thank you.

Greetz,
Roland!

[webView (no fullscreen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YVTr.png)

Comment: How is your UIWebView bound to the parent view?

Comment: Ohh, i don't know :(

How I can do this?
I use the Xamarin Studio.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: are you doing this in code, or using the UI Designer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to get that fullscreen, basically you just do a zoom out on the content in the scrollView. I have done so many ways to fix that, but this is the legit one. change the value 0.5 into any number you want and that value is supposed to be < 1 because you zoom it out the content.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   webView.scrollView.zoomScale = 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should obviously use Constraints:

1. Click on UIWebView control twice, you'll see that small T-figures which you could drag and create constraints;
2. Select created constraint in DocumentOutline;
3. Set desired values in Properties window:

[image]